# Frontloading mod_rewrite rule is causing index.php to load twice

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've been working on a project that uses a frontloader to handle all requests (Routing domain.com/args/go/here to Index.php?req=args/go/here), and it's worked very well... Or I should say, I thought it did - I recently added a new logger, and to test it I placed a test log message in index.php. This message was being written to my log file twice, every time I reloaded the page, and after much debugging I found the cause to be my .htaccess file - for whatever reason, it loads index.php twice for every request.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/beta/ #I added this after I discovered the bug
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php$ #This too. Doesn't work
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?args=$1 [L]
```

I've also tried:

```
FallbackResource /site/beta/index.php
```

Which both doesn't work (Index.php just doesn't load if you try to go to, say, 127.0.0.1/site/beta/admin/controls/ - but it does if you just go to /index.php), and still loads twice.

Is anyone able to help me? I spent a few hours in IRC, and no one could come up with a solution that worked. (The two above are the only ones suggested)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you completly sure it's a mod_rewrite bug? If you enable RewriteLog file with a high rewriteLogLevel (9) do you see the same requests handled 2 times?

For me every time I see the 'same request done 2 times' I think about another strange web bug: **The empty IMG src bug**.

If you have somewhere in your HTML an

```
<IMG SRC="">
```

or in one of the css (harder to find) a:

```
url()
```

Then you've got it. HTTP protocol dictate that an empty GET url (and an image or url() in css is a GET implicit request) MUST be a call to the same url as the one which render the original page (and it can be a POST as well if you get your page as a POST request).

There're really few reason to have a mod_rewrite responding 2 times to one single request. Check with Firebug or LiveHTTP Requests that you're not always sending the index.php request 2 times. Or test your server with a telnet-mode HTTP request, by hand, as this will certainly send only one request.

Comment: You are amazing - thank you so much. Turns out while testing my header (HTML header) constructor, I had added a test line to load a non-existent javascript file.

Comment: for completion, also check favicon requests. If they get redirected to the bootsraper strange things could happen.

Comment: Missing `www/favicon.ico` for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be the browser trying to load (invisibly it seems unless you check the apache access logs) favicon.ico.  I had the same issue until I put one in my sites root directory.  I know the issue was resolved for the initial asker, I'm putting this here for people like myself looking for an answer to the same question.

Comment: Yep. This. Favicon -> 404 -> Controller. -- Cheers, thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

Old issue, but adding this as it is a problem.

If you are using mod_rewrite and have everything pointing to your index page, chances are that you might get a favicon request directed to index as well, causing a reload of your page.

Whitelist '/favicon.ico' in your htaccess file to eliminate this problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35371103)