# Why is this htaccess running everything twice?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The script (index.php) gets called twice every time someone visits /confirm/xyz123

Why?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule confirm/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+) /confirm/index.php?hashidemail=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Turns out it was a problem with IIS Mod-Rewrite.

To fix the problem, I just uninstalled and reinstalled IIS Mod-Rewrite (this time in ASAPI mode, which is an option in the setup process).

Hopefully anyone else who finds themselves with the same problem will find this post.

Cheers.

Comment: Perhaps you should retag your question then. IIS != Apache :)

Answer (score 0):

Check that previous response [frontloading-mod-rewrite-rule-is-causing-index-php-to-load-twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623469/frontloading-mod-rewrite-rule-is-causing-index-php-to-load-twice/4623745#4623745).

Test that a request via telnet or wget is really making this thing run twice, if not it's an empty GEt somewhere in your previous content.